# rails_12factor gem issue about deploying

Tags: ruby-on-rails, exception, localhost

I loaded up the rails server on localhost:3000 and I got the error below. I found out it was the 'rails_12factor' gem that was causing the problem. I'm using this gem to get my css to work on my herokuapp, but its causing issues on localhost. Is there a way to get rails_12factor to work on local as well?

I'm running rails 4.0/ruby 2.0, and I heard I needed 'rails_12factor' to get css to work with rails 4 and heroku..

This is the error:

```
    wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)

Rails.root: /home/brice/rails_projects/blog

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
activesupport (4.0.0.rc1) lib/active_support/core_ext/kernel/reporting.rb:82:in `capture'
activerecord (4.0.0.rc1) lib/active_record/migration.rb:363:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.0.0.rc1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:392:in `_run__553013214532738530__call__callbacks'
activesupport (4.0.0.rc1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.0.0.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:64:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
railties (4.0.0.rc1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
railties (4.0.0.rc1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:21:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.0.0.rc1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (4.0.0.rc1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:25:in `tagged'
activesupport (4.0.0.rc1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `tagged'
railties (4.0.0.rc1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:21:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (4.0.0.rc1) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:83:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
railties (4.0.0.rc1) lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in `call'
railties (4.0.0.rc1) lib/rails/application.rb:96:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
/home/brice/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
/home/brice/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
/home/brice/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
```

I can provide other files too, but I have no idea where to look. If anyone has an idea how to get around this, I'd greatly appreciate it!

Comment: Are you able to run rake db:migrate successfully?

Comment: hey Vimsha, i found out it was a gem issue, and revised the question. but i didn't do rake db:migrate before pushing to heroku either, would that solve the new issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was to append 'group: :production' to the end of rails_12factor

so it would look like this on your gemfile:

```
gem 'rails_12factor', group: :production
```